# RxJava's Observable.create vs Observable.just(1).flatMap

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I've been doing a bit of RxJava and i often find myself in the case where I need to transform some existing code result to an observable.

For instance let's take the following:

```java
ListenableFuture<T> result = request.executeAsync();
return result;
```

So the easiest way to transform this to an observable is to do

```java
ListenableFuture<T> result = request.executeAsync();
return Observable.from(result);
```

The thing is that `executeAsync` actually executes the request when it's called. What I want is to delay that call until the observable is subscribed to.

I thought of two ways of doing this

```java
return Observable.create { aSubscriber ->
    if (!aSubscriber.unsubscribed) {
        aSubscriber.onNext(request.executeAsync())
    }
    if (!aSubscriber.unsubscribed) {
        aSubscriber.onCompleted()
    }
}
```

and

```java
return Observable
    .just(1)
    .flatMap((_) -> Observable.from(request.executeAsync()));
```

It looks to me like it's simpler to use the flatMap option as I don't have to bother with the subscriber logic.

**Is there any pitfall in using `flatMap` over `create` ? Is there a preferred Rx way to ease integration ?**

Thanks

Comment: As a matter of fact, create() has way more pitfalls than flatMap().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  defer instead :

```
Observable.defer(() -> request.executeAsync())
          .concatMap(Observable::from)
          .subscribe();
```

Comment: Whops. Answer too fast : defer won't solve your issue.

Comment: I must ask: how does this not solve my issue ? it looks to me like it would defer the call until the observable is subscribed to. Or do i misunderstand the documentation ?

Comment: Because it will emit the `ListenableFuture` and not the value of the `ListenableFuture`. So I edit my answer to emit the value.

Comment: This looks like it could work but i would have just gone with `Observable.defer(() -> Observable.from(request.executeAsync()))`. Am I missing something or would this behave like I expect ?

Answer (score 0):

[RxJavaGuava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJavaGuava) is a small library which converts `ListenableFuture` to `Observable` for you, so you'd better use this than a "home-made" solution.
It allows you to write

```
ListenableFutureObservable.from(request.executeAsync(), Schedulers.computation())
```

Depending on what the request does, you'll have to pick the right scheduler.

Comment: There's actually nothing home-made in my post. It's all basic built-in RxJava. I'm not sure what you propose would change anything compared to RxJava's `Observable.from(request.executeAsync())` as this would in any case execute the request as soon as it's called.

Comment: @Crystark you're right, what I proposed would also have to be wrapped in an `Observable.defer`. But then the `Observable.defer(() -> Observable.from(request.executeAsync()))` that you suggested is simpler, so you can just go with that (unless you want to run the request on an RxJava thread pool, then RxJavaGuava is helpful).

Comment: Ok thanks. FYI, I think you can run the request on a thread pool with built-in RxJava too using `Observable.from(Future, Scheduler)`